# Simplifying LEFT JOINs

Tags: mysql, left-join

So I have this query:

```
  SELECT c1.field1, c2.field2
  FROM table1 c1
  LEFT JOIN table1 c2 ON c1.field1 = c2.field1 AND c1.field2 = :arg1 AND c2.field2 <> :arg1
  LEFT JOIN table2 cc ON c2.field2 = cc.field2 AND cc.field3 = :arg2
  WHERE (c2.field2 IS NULL OR cc.field2 IS NOT NULL)
  ORDER BY ISNULL(c2.field2) ASC
```

This does two things:

1. Picks up `table1.field1` for a given `field2` value.
2. Picks up a `table1.field2` for which field1 is the same as in the previous point that also has a specific propery from a second table. (It's only this complicated because of normalization) If this doesn't exist then return `NULL`.

While this works it's really ugly. Is there a simpler version doing the same? I am mostly bothered how the second `JOIN` needs to be a `LEFT` followed by this `WHERE`. I felt `INNER` should be simpler but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please add some sample data and sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to transfer left join into `union` and `inner join`, then you can get a new query like this:

```
SELECT c1.field1, null as field2
FROM table1 c1
  UNION ALL
SELECT c1.field1, c2.field2
FROM table1 c1
INNER JOIN table1 c2 ON c1.field1 = c2.field1 
INNER JOIN table2 cc ON c2.field2 = cc.field2 
WHERE c1.field2 = :arg1 AND c2.field2 <> :arg1 AND cc.field3 = :arg2
```

Firstly, I transfer your original query from `join` into `union` by splitting the where clause like this:

```
SELECT c1.field1, c2.field2
FROM table1 c1
LEFT JOIN table1 c2 ON c1.field1 = c2.field1 AND c1.field2 = :arg1 AND c2.field2 <> :arg1
WHERE (c2.field2 IS NULL )
  UNION ALL
SELECT c1.field1, c2.field2
FROM table1 c1
INNER JOIN table1 c2 ON c1.field1 = c2.field1 AND c1.field2 = :arg1 AND c2.field2 <> :arg1
LEFT JOIN table2 cc ON c2.field2 = cc.field2 AND cc.field3 = :arg2
WHERE (c2.field2 IS NOT NULL AND cc.field2 IS NOT NULL)
```

But the first part of union can keep transfer like this:

```
SELECT c1.field1, null
FROM table1 c1
WHERE c1.field2 <> :arg1 --c2.field2 must be null
  UNION ALL
SELECT c1.field1, c2.field2
FROM table1 c1
LEFT JOIN table1 c2 ON c1.field1 = c2.field1  AND c2.field2 <> :arg1
WHERE c1.field2 = :arg1 AND c2.field2 IS NULL
```

At the end, I get the top query that transfer all left join into union and inner join.

I don't have any data, so I'm not sure I'm right or not. Wish it helps.

Comment: The first SELECT misses a `WHERE c1.field2 = :arg1` otherwise great. I always forget about `UNION`.